# Excel - Call function from other cell

Tags: vba, excel

First of all I would like to tell you that I have just basics with VBA or Visual Basic. So probably there will be better solution in VBA, but I was unable to find a way. That's why that my attempt is so crude. Also my english can be somewhat broken sometimes. I'm sorry for that.

Below you can find screenshots from my excel sheet. You can notice functions are in czech language. You can find translation below.

Screenshot with actual results:

[image: Screenshot with actual results]

Screenshot with actual functions:

[image: Screenshot with actual functions]

**Translated functions:**

```
AA =COUNTIFS(A:A;X2;D:D;D129)   
AB =IF(AA129=1;CELL("address";INDEX(D:D;MATCH(D129;D:D;0)));"NULL")
AC =IF(AA129=1;REPLACE(AB129;2;1;"M");"NULL")
AD =IF(AA129=1;CONCATENATE("=IF(";"""";M129;"""";"=";AC129;";1;0)");"NULL")
AF =ISNUMBER(AE129)
AG =IF(AF129=TRUE;CONCATENATE(AE129);0)
```

**Description:**

Every day someone downloads .csv files from JIRA and uploads it to excel. That csv contains test cases. Column X has the date when this csv was uploaded, Column D has the ID of the test case. Column M has the date of the last change on that test case.

**Functions description:**

AA: It searches if there is the same test case in previous day. If yes, then result is 1. If no, Result is 0.

AB: Locates the exact cell location of the same test case from previous day.

AC: Serves for translation from ID column (D) to last change column (M).

AD: Composes translated information from AC, so it will create a function, which I would like to use further. That function will compare last change date with the test case from previous day and current day. Result should be 1 or 0 depending on if there was any change.

AF: Checks if AE is number (AE should be the column where I would like to run 
that function from AD).

AG: If AF is true, then it copies value from AE. Else it's 0

**Problem is:**

I can't find a way to trick excel to take the text from AD and use it as function in another cell. Tried to program it in VBA, but failed.

**What I need:**

Translate result from AD from text to function and then run it in AE.

If there is a more efficient way to program this, I am open to suggestions. But I would like to have an answer for my question as well. I want to know if it's possible because I will make more complicated cases later while I learn to work with VBA.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: replace AD with `=IF(AA129=1;IF(M129=INDEX(M:M;MATCH(D129;D:D;0));1;0);"NULL")` and you can skip AB and AC

Comment: @ScottCraner: I see. Can this be used as compare if that 2 dates are some or not? As far I can see it returns 1 if they are same and 0 if not.

Comment: It is your formula, I just combined the three into one working formula.  So if  AA129  does not equal 1 it returns `NULL`.  If AA129 is `1` then If M129 equals the return of the INDEX Formula then it returns `1` if it does not match then it returns `0`

Comment: Ok. Thanks alot for the help :)

Comment: @ScottCraner would you mind posting your formula as an answer so the question shows as answered. Thanks for the help